# What is correct order to configure service applications on SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-server, service-application

Is there any order to configure service application? Is there any dependency?

Please guide me.

Comment: What service applications you are planning?

Comment: Access Services,
Business Data Connectivity ,
Excel ,
Managed Metadata ,
PerformancePoint ,
Search ,
Secure Store ,
State ,
Usage and Health ,
User Profile ,
Visio Graphics ,
Web Analytics ,
Word Automation

Answer (score 1):

Their is no hard and fast rule about the order of the Service Application configurations. But here what we did.

1. State Service
2. Usage And health
3. Managed Metadata
4. User Profile Service( for social features you need MMS before it and Mysite host Web Application)
5. Search Service( for people search you need UPA and MMS before)
6. Secure Store Service
   Renaming you can install in any order because No hard dependencies on other service applications. But all EE services required other components i.e install SQL component etc.

Comment: App management in 2010?

Comment: I missed the 2010 part, i thought it is for 2013.

Answer (score 0):

There is specific sequence but there are services which has dependency on others. I would suggest to use [autospinstaller](https://autospinstaller.codeplex.com) to provision all SharePoint servers including service applications which follow a recommended sequence and setup the correct permissions. Below is the recommended sequence of Service applications installation:

1. Create StateServiceApp
2. Create MetadataServiceApp
   3.ConfigureClaimsToWindowsTokenService
3. Create UserProfileService Application
4. Create SPUsageApp
5. ConfigureUsageLogging
6. Create WebAnalyticsApp
7. Create SecureStoreServiceApp
8. ConfigureFoundationSearch
9. ConfigureTracing
10. Create EnterpriseSearchServiceApp
11. Create BusinessDataConnectivityServiceApp
12. Create ExcelServiceApp
13. Create Access2010ServiceApp
14. Create VisioServiceApp
15. Create PerformancePointServiceApp
16. Create WordAutomationServiceApp
17. Create ProjectServerServiceApp
18. ConfigureWorkflowTimerService